# different versions of eb cli if running under super user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I run in the shell (Ubuntu):

```
sudo eb --version
```

I get

```
EB CLI 3.4.5 (Python 2.7.6)
```

However, if I run

```
eb --version
```

I get

```
AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface v2.6.3
```

I wonder why it happens?

Comment: You probably still have the 2.6 version installed in your user path.

Comment: why it looks for another path with super user rights?

Comment: Yes. If you use "sudo" you are using the "super user" rights, paths, etc. So anything that is user specific (like in your bashrc) you wont have access to while using sudo. (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path) You really should remove the 2.6 from your path anyways.